# Github for Windows stopped working

Tags: commit, github-for-windows

I am trying to commit a repository on github through the github GUI in windows. My repository size is of 63 MB. After writing the commit message when i commit it crashes. Windows shows message as "**Github stopped working**". What could be the problem and how to rectify it?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's Window's general error message for "it crashed". We're unlikely to be able to help you. Your best bet would be to try a command line client on the same files to see if you can rule out repository corruption (and push your commit), but other than that you'll have to ask GitHub for support.

Comment: I can't get instant updates from there...the reason i posted it on SO that if someone faced the same issue they can help me. @Arkain

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web based service

Comment: @Mark no, [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) is a desktop app, and might arguably be a tool used primarily for programming.